# Vertically bottom Align Text in TextFormField Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

So I know that you can Align the contents in a textformfield through the

> textAlignVertical

property. I tried this on my TextFormField:

```
 TextFormField(
                        textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.bottom,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color:
                                isUnlocked ? Color(0xffF6CD9D) : Colors.grey),
                        cursorColor: Color(0xffF6CD9D),
                        enabled: isUnlocked,
                        controller: vornameController,
                        decoration: new InputDecoration(
                          focusColor: Color(0xffF6CD9D),
                          hoverColor: Color(0xffF6CD9D),
                          enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xffF6CD9D)),
                          ),
                          focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xffF6CD9D)),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

But I want the text to be on the line itself. How can I achieve this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add is dense true and content padding

```dart
decoration: InputDecoration(
     isDense: true,
     contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
     ...
   ),
```